# Moving artifacts from remote repositories to a local one

Tags: artifactory, remote-repository

Preventing pulling in new dependencies from one build to the next, due to the way 3rd parties could define their dependencies.

Currently I'm utilizing the Remote Repositories in JFrog Artifact which reduces the downloads from public repos.

In my build scripts I can hard code the versions of the 3rd party modules/libraries I want to pull in.  But if one of the dependencies hasn't it could pull in a new version on the next build.

So was curious if it there was a feature within JFrog Artifactory to copy an artifact and it's dependency from a remote repo into a local repo ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept of virtual repo's in artifacory that is a combination of remote and loca repo.

local repo --> mostly used for custom build/artifacts/packages

remote repo --> points to the repo server of the technology configured.

For eg. with npm virtual repo.

npm local --> custom packages

npm remote --> https://www.npmjs.com/~npmre